# javascript's jquery prev().remove() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form the user put values and submit and an image of cross is also appended at the same time as a sibling. I want the image to when clicked remove itself and it's previous sibling. But it's not working

```
$newform.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $newform.find('input:text').val();
    var url = document.getElementById('addurl').value;
    $list.append('<li class="links"><a href="'+ url +'"><div class="spann">' + text +'</div></a></li>');
    $list.append('<img src="images/close.png" class="cross">');
});
$('.cross').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Did you see what $(this) returns in the function? If you have your images wrapped with <div> or <li>, the $(this).prev() may not return anything. Please post the html as well, so that its easier to provide an answer

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/535480

Comment: @Akash Pinnaka, no the image is not appended inside any element. It is appended naked .